# Sort serial data with buffer

Tags: algorithm, sorting, serial-port, buffer

Is there any algorithms to sort data from serial input using buffer which is smaller than data length?

For example, I have 100 bytes of serial data, which can be read only once, and 40 bytes buffer. And I need to print out sorted bytes.

I need it in Javascript, but any general ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I'm quite certain it's not possible unless the data is pre-ordered to at least some degree. If the last byte you receive should be first in the output, you *can't* have output any bytes before it, and still have it come out first, but you can't save all the intervening data in a buffer smaller than that data occupies. You could try something like compressing the data, but that can backfire and make it larger.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of sorting is not possible in a single pass.

Using your example:  suppose you have filled your 40 byte buffer, so you need to start printing out bytes in order to make room for the next one.  In order to print out sorted data, you must print the smallest byte first.  However, if the smallest byte has not been read, you can't possibly print it out yet!

The closest relevant fit to your question may be [external sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) algorithms, which take multiple passes in order to sort data that can't fit into memory.  That is, if you have peripherals that can store the output of a processing pass, you can sort data larger than your memory in O(log(N/M)) passes, where N is the size of the problem, and M is the size of your memory.

The classic storage peripheral for external sorting is the tape drive; however, the same algorithms work for disk drives (of whatever kind).  Also, as cache hierarchies grow in depth, the principles of external sorting become more relevant even for in-memory sorts -- try taking a look at [cache-oblivious](http://kristoffer.vinther.name/academia/thesis/) algorithms.